# Kotlin android data binding issue fails in app:kaptDebugKotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, kapt

after enabling both data binding and view binding

```
`
buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
      
    }`
```

and started giving this error while running app but not while syncing gradle. Tried clean/rebuild and invalidate cache & restart, nothing is helping.Everything added correctly in gradle.

```
    > Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin
                ^
  symbol:   class ConstraintLayout
  location: class ActivityAeBinding app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/out/com/packagename/databinding/ActivityAeBinding.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
  private ActivityAeBinding(@NonNull ConstraintLayout rootView) {
                                     ^
  symbol:   class ConstraintLayout
  location: class ActivityAeBinding /app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/out/com/databinding/ActivityAeBinding.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
  public ConstraintLayout getRoot() {
         ^
  symbol:   class ConstraintLayout
  location: class ActivityAeBinding

> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

This is the problematic class that the compiler is complaining about while running app

```
// Generated by view binder compiler. Do not edit!
package com.example.databinding;

import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.viewbinding.ViewBinding;
import com.sah.android.apps.mydrawer.R;
import java.lang.NullPointerException;
import java.lang.Override;

public final class ActivityAeBinding implements ViewBinding {
  @NonNull
  private final ConstraintLayout rootView;

  private ActivityAeBinding(@NonNull ConstraintLayout rootView) {
    this.rootView = rootView;
  }

  @Override
  @NonNull
  public ConstraintLayout getRoot() {
    return rootView;
  }

  @NonNull
  public static ActivityAeBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater) {
    return inflate(inflater, null, false);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static ActivityAeBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      @Nullable ViewGroup parent, boolean attachToParent) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_ae, parent, false);
    if (attachToParent) {
      parent.addView(root);
    }
    return bind(root);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static ActivityAeBinding bind(@NonNull View rootView) {
    if (rootView == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("rootView");
    }

    return new ActivityAeBinding((ConstraintLayout) rootView);
  }
}
```

Comment: adding `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in the module level `build.gradle` helped me

Comment: its already there,what strange is that class is pointing to its a generated class not part of the project

Comment: I suggest you to upload activity class nd xml, might help you in debugging quicker

Comment: Maybe this is what you should add to dependencies, `implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4"`

Comment: all dependencies are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering it because want to show the emphasis of when something peculiar is wrong with your data binding or view binding it's almost certain that there is some issue in layout files.

As with my case the confusing part was the generated binding class was not part of my project idk why it was generating but after searching all my layout files I discovered one import from support library not androidx thus creating this weird issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) at the same time.

I suggest you to remove either of them and try again.
If you still face challenge, then post complete files.

Please note that, `View Binding` is intended to handle simpler use cases and the limitations of `View Binding` are covered in `Data Binding`. The later handles complex functionality. Please read their documentations completely for more clarity.

Also, kindly visit this [page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and then navigate to section **Comparison with data binding**

And then finally, please go through this already answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557650/databinding-not-work-together-with-viewbinding-in-kotlin).

Comment: Actually, it's stated [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) that you can use both view binding and data binding in the same project. you probably meant that you can't use them in the same layout.

Comment: I agree to your point, however when the say **"you can use both view binding and data binding in the same project".** They mean that you can include both view and data binding in your project, but you can't use them together on the same layout. The restriction is `per-layout` and not `per-project`.

Comment: I'm not using both for the same layout,actually i'm not using data binding at all right now,it's only giving this error while running app not while gradle sync.

Comment: Please post all files for us to review further

Comment: added the problematic class that the compiler is referiing to